# How to execute Linux command or shell script from APACHE JMETER

Tags: jmeter

How to execute Linux command or shell script from APACHE JMETER

Do anyone know how to execute linux commands from Jmeter? 
I found this link online http://www.technix.in/execute-linux-command-shell-script-apache-jmeter/ and I tried the steps, but is not working. I can't see the SSH Sampler. 
If anyone had any success with running shell scripts from Jmeter please share.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute a command on remote system take the following steps:

1. Download [JSch.jar](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) - the library which provides SSH and SCP protocols operations from Java language and place it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation
2. Download [groovy-all.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all) - Groovy scripting engine support for Jmeter and drop it to the /lib folder as well
3. Restart JMeter to pick the libraries up
4. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan and choose "groovy" from "Language" drop-down
5. Follow example code from [Exec.java](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html) Jsch tutorial to implement your own logic.

You can also refer to below snippet which executes `ls` command on a remote *nix system and returns command execution result. Make sure that you provide valid `username`, `hostname` and `password` in order so sampler could work

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

JSch jSch = new JSch();
Session session = jSch.getSession("username", "hostname", 22);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setPassword("password");
session.connect();

Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

String command = "ls";
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
channel.setInputStream(null);
((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);
InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

channel.connect();
StringBuilder rv = new StringBuilder();
rv.append("New system date: ");
byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
while (true) {
  while (in.available() > 0) {
      int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
      if (i < 0) break;
      rv.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
  }
  if (channel.isClosed()) {
      break;
  }
  try {
      Thread.sleep(100);
  } catch (Exception ee) {
      ee.printStackTrace();
  }
}
in.close();
channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();        
SampleResult.setResponseData(rv.toString().getBytes());
```

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](http://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) for details on Groovy scripting engine installation and best scripting practices.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replies. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at OS Process Sampler which is done for this and available in core:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Beanshell scripting inside jmeter then you can have some thing like that:

```
    String command="your command here";
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = 
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            output.append(line + "\n");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    log.inf(output.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/How-to-execute-jar-from-OS-Process-Sampler-in-Linux-td5724442.html)
this answer about execute jar-file. But idea the same for other OS-command.

1. Use OS_Process_Sampler
2. Fill field **command** with OS shell, like /bin/bash or analogue.
3. Set first argument with **-c**
4. Set next argument with **you command**
5. Sampler ready to execute :)